# Serializing XSD.exe-created object model. How to set XmlAnyAttribute values

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, system.xml

I have an object-model created by `xsd.exe` which has this member:

XSD:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:anyAttribute />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Generated C# (abridged)

```
[XmlAnyAttribute]
public XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr { get... set... }
```

Deserialization is fine and this property is populated when I load an XML file like this:

```
<Foo bar="baz" one="one" two="three" four="ten" />
```

The problem is, how do I *serialize*? I cannot simply set `fooInstance.AnyAttr = new XmlAttribute[]` and then create each `XmlAttribute` object to go inside the `AnyAttr` collection because the `XmlAttribute` constructor is internal and can only be created by `XmlDocument.CreateAttribute`. However, in the current context there is no `XmlDocument` instance available.

So how do I create an instance of `XmlAttribute` suitable for use with `[XmlAnyAttribute]`?

Comment: I found that you can do `XmlAttribute attr = new XmlDocument().CreateAttribute("name"); attr.Value = "your_content_here";` but if the attribute comes from another namespace (which in my case it does) it's not enough. Please do update if you find a solution.

Comment: @Chris I used a dummy instance of `XmlDocument` which worked for me as my XML file has a single default schema. I'm sorry I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can use a dummy instance of `XmlDocument` to create XML DOM components with and it works fine:

```
FooElement foo = new FooElement();
foo.bar = "baz";

XmlDocument dummy = new XmlDocument();
foo.AnyAttr = new XmlAttribute[] {
    dummy.CreateAttribute("one", "one"),
    dummy.CreateAttribute("two", "three"),
    dummy.CreateAttribute("four", "ten")
};
```